# How to get complementary lines from two text files?

Tags: regex, text, comparison, diff, complement

How to get complementary lines from two text files?

File `file1.txt` has

```
123 foo
234 bar
...
```

File `file2.txt` has

```
123 foo
333 foobar
234 bar
...
```

I want to get all lines in `file1.txt` and not in `file2.txt`.  The two files are hundreds of MB large and contain non-ASCII characters.  What's a fast way to do this?

Comment: No.  If sorting them is helpful for solving my question, it could be a step in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines, specifically?

```
fgrep -vxf file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: +1 for using `fgrep` but not programming from scratch (unnecessarily).  But this should have room for improving the timing.  Treating each line in file2.txt as regex seems too wasteful?

Comment: `fgrep` doesn't treat anything as a regex.

Answer (score 2):

For good performance with large files, don't read much of the file into memory; work with what's on disk as much as possible.

String-matching can be done efficiently with hashing.

One strategy:

1. Scan the first file line-by-line.  For each line:

   - Hash the string for the line.  The hashing algorithm you use does matter; `djb2` is one example but there are many.
   - Put the key into a hash-set structure.  Do not keep the string data.
2. Scan the second file line-by-line.  For each line:

   - Hash the string for the line.
   - If the hash key is not found in the set from the first file:

     - Write the string data for this line to the output where you're tracking the different lines (e.g. standard output or another file).  The hash didn't match so this line appears in the 2nd file but not the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

"Hundreds of MB" is not so much.

I would solve this task this way (in Perl):

```
$ cat complementary.pl 
my %f;

open(F, "$ARGV[1]") or die "Can't open file2: $ARGV[1]\n";
$f[$_] = 1 while(<F>);
close(F);

open(F, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open file1: $ARGV[0]\n";
while(<F>) {
    print if not defined $f[$_];
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
100 a
200 b
300 c

$ cat file2.txt 
200 b
100 a
400 d

$ perl complementary.pl file1.txt file2.txt 
300 c
```

Comment: Will this scale well if the text files are each 2+ GB?

Comment: It depends on the box where it's running

Comment: It's Mac OS X 10.6.8, 8 GB RAM.

Comment: I think it will not. The program need to be rewritten to analyze files blockwise to be really scalable